# send email even with addError (platform event)

Tags: apex, platform-event, send-email, emailmessage, adderror

I need help to understanding why I can't send email even using platform event (publish immediately).

The business logic is to prevent duplicated lead basead on a field, show an error message in the UI and send email to the manager with the existing lead and who tried to create it.

**trigger**

```
trigger TriggerLead on Lead (before update, after update, before insert, after insert) {
   if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        duplicityRule.checkLeadDuplicity(trigger.new);
   }
}
```

**handler**

```
public with sharing class DuplicityRule{
 public static void checkLeadDuplicity(List<Lead> newLeads){
 Set<String> setDoc = new Set<String>();
        for(Lead ld :newLeads){
            setDoc.add(ld.DB_Doc__c);
        }

        if(setDoc.size() > 0){
            List<Lead> lstLead = [SELECT Id, DB_Doc__c FROM Lead WHERE DB_Doc__c in :setDoc AND DB_Doc__c != null LIMIT 1];

            Map<String, Lead> mapDocWiseLead = new Map<String, Lead>();
            for(Lead ld :lstLead){
                mapDocWiseLead.put(ld.DB_Doc__c, ld);
            }

            for(Lead ld :newLeads){
                if(mapDocWiseLead.containsKey(ld.DB_Doc__c)){
                    System.debug('Duplicated!');
                    SendEmailLeadDupl__e eventMail = new SendEmailLeadDupl__e(Lead_Id__c = lstLead[0].Id);
                    Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(eventMail);
                    if(sr.isSuccess()){
                        System.debug('Success publ event.');
                    } else {                        
                        System.debug('Error publ event.');
                    }

                    ld.DB_Doc__c.addError('Lead already exists.');
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

**platform event**

```
trigger sendEmailLeadDupl on SendEmailLeadDupl__e (after insert) {
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailsToSendList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 
    for(SendEmailLeadDupl__e event :Trigger.New){
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'xyz@gmail.com'};

        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        //mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
        mail.setReplyTo('xyz@gmail.com');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
        mail.setSubject('Lead duplicated');
        mail.setBccSender(false);
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Lead duplicated');
        mail.setHtmlBody('employee {{x}} tried to create an existing lead {{Lead A}}');

        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
}
```

The log USER_DEBUG [28]|DEBUG|Success publ event.

any idea how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to surmise that your Platform Event is running as `Automated Process` user. [This user can't use Messaging.SingleEmailMessage `send()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_api_considerations.htm?q=email)

> No Email Support from a Platform Event Trigger
>
> With the default Automated Process running user, sending an email message from a platform event trigger using the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage class isn’t supported. The email can’t be sent because the sender is the Automated Process entity, which has no email address. To send an email, change the running user of the trigger. For more information, see Configure the User and Batch Size for Your Platform Event Trigger with PlatformEventSubscriberConfig.

You need to either use Process Automation (Flow) to send the email, or better, have the Platform Event run in the context of a different user

This is done with the metadata [`PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm) which you can configure using your IDE or via normal package.xml deploy commands via, say, Workbench

Comment: It is possible to add a perm set to the Automated Process user to enable sending, but it is a fudge and using a different user makes more sense.

Comment: @philw there are other limitations as well including no/limited support for VF email  components and lots of restrictions on merge fields in text/html templates (at least when I last banged my head on this in 2018/19 before the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig came along)